# sqlite3 - combine multiple commands into one line

Tags: sqlite

Run below command from sqlite prompt:

```
.headers on; SELECT _id,_data,parent FROM files where _data like '%Pictures%'
```

Will get a error:

```
Usage: .headers on|off
```

But run two commands one by one works fine.

What's the right way to combine multiple commands into one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

".header" is command to the sqlite3 command tool, not SQL itself.  You can't combine sqlite3 commands with SQL in the way you wish.

Comment: If so, how can I get the column name also when execute sql command with on command? or it's not possible at all?

Comment: You can use the `PRAGMA table_info()` to get that information.  See http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info

Comment: @lucky1928 You can give multiple lines to the `sqlite3` tool. But how to do that depends on the shell used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this search result and lucky1928's comment made me notice that this works for all normal shells

```
echo '.headers on
SELECT _id,_data,parent FROM files where _data like '\''%Pictures%'\''
' | sqlite3 mydatabase.db
```

The multi-line argument **must** be given to an echo command, it doesn't work as a direct argument to the sqlite3 command because sqlite3 does not support multi-line sqlite3 commands on the command line in a single argument.

HOWEVER, this also works:

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.db '.headers on' 'SELECT _id,_data,parent FROM files where _data like '\''%Pictures%'\''
```

That is make the lines individual arguments to the sqlite3 command line.